# Parameterized Type Mismatch in Java

Tags: java, class, derived-class, derived, parameterized-types

I have three types, A, B, and X

```
A<T extends Object> extends X
B extends Object
```

And there's this api call

```
doSomething(List<X>)
```

And I'm doing this call

```
doSomething(ImmutableList.<A<B>>of(new A<B>(), new A<B>()))
```

But I'm getting error:

```
List<X> cannot be applied to ImmutableList<A<B>>
```

Shouldn't A essentially be X? How to make this working?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the declaration with an [upper bounded wildcard](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)

```
doSomething(List<? extends X>)
```

`List<S>` is not a subtype of `List<T>` even if `S` is a subtype of `T`

You can think about why this is in quite simple terms.

If `Dog` and `Cat` are subtypes of `Animal` and your method is `doSomething(List<Animal> pets)`, then inside the method you might `add` a `Cat`. But what if `pets` was passed as a `List<Dog>`? You might get an allergic reaction.

**Enter the wildcard**

You can therefore use wildcards to do this. The *wildcard parameterized type* `List<? extends Animal>` represents: "(a type from) the set of all parameterized types - formed by invoking the generic type `List<T>` - with a type argument that is *any type* (usually called an "*an unknown type*") - that is a subtype of `Animal` (inclusive)".

By implication this is a potentially infinite set, as you could have an infinite number of subtypes of `Animal` <sub>(and subtypes of List mumble mumble complicating issue mumble)</sub>.

**"*in*" parameters**

Using `List<? extends Animal>` says "*I agree to treat everything in this list as, at best, an `Animal`*". In simple terms you can no longer `add(e)` anything to that list because inside the method you don't know if it is a `List<Dog>`, `List<Cat>` or `List<Animal>` at the calling site. You can however `get(index)` any item from that list parameter and `feed()` it (assuming `feed()` is a method on `Animal`). It is an "*in*" parameter: it provides data to the method.

tldr: An `extends` bound implies an "in" variable (one that you extract data from, not one that you put data into)

**"*out*" parameters**

If you want to `add(e)` a `Dog` into the list you need to change the method declaration to an "*out*" variable by declaring `doSomething(List<? super Dog>)`. Now you are saying "*I can treat this list as holding any type that is a supertype of `Dog`*": at the calling site it may be a `List<Dog>`, `List<Animal>` or `List<Object>`. You can now `add(e)` either a `Dog`, or a *subtype* of `Dog`, like a `Mongrel`: all will be compatible with any of the possible types of list that are passed. You can't add a `Cat` as that would make no sense: the list at the calling site could still be a `List<Dog>`, not a `List<Animal>`.

tldr: It is an "*out*" parameter: it "stores" data from inside the method, (and can therefore provide it back to the calling site).

Refs: The Java Tutorials > [Upper bounded wildcards](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/upperBounded.html)